# Function estimation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of chest measures and I need to find the size that fits as many measures that it can. If I need to find 1 size it's easy as I can minimize the function $(x−a)^2$ with $x$ as size estimated and $a$ as chest measure. And I will have the average as a result.

I need to estimate 2 sizes that if $a$ fits better than $b$ I only get value from $a$ size and of course, get as many fitted measures. I want to solve it with Solver so I can't use IF function. If you recommend another program I will take a loot at it.

I don't know if I need to explain myself better

Comment: An example would help to understand what you need.

Comment: Is your problem as suggested in Mark's answer, i.e. minimizing \sum_{i=1}^n $\min \{ (x_i-a)^2,(x_i-b)^2 \}$ over $a,b$?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple groups you're trying to match against, you need to optimize 
$$
min((x - a)^2, (x - b)^2) 
$$
for the values of a and b.